# The properties of the file for records generated by jooq are always set to Optional

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jooq

I have created the User table and `generateJooq` generates UserRecord.kt, but always the properties of the `UserRecord` class are optional.
I would like to know how to avoid sharing optional properties.

By the way, the schema of the User table is Not Null.

### DB schema

```sql
CREATE TABLE user
(
    id    varchar(256) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    email varchar(256)        NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

### build.gradle.kts

```
:

jooq {
    configurations {
        create("main") {
            jooqConfiguration.apply {
                jdbc.apply {
                    url = System.getenv("DB_URL")
                    user = System.getenv("DB_USER")
                    password = System.getenv("DB_PASS")
                }
                generator.apply {
                    name = "org.jooq.codegen.KotlinGenerator"
                    database.apply {
                        name = "org.jooq.meta.mysql.MySQLDatabase"
                        inputSchema = System.getenv("DB_NAME")
                        excludes = "flyway_schema_history"
                    }
                    generate.apply {
                        isDeprecated = false
                        isTables = true
                        isComments = true
                    }
                    target.apply {
                        packageName = "com.example.infra.jooq"
                        directory = "${buildDir}/generated/source/jooq/main"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Generated UserRecord.kt

```
:


/**
 * This class is generated by jOOQ.
 */
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
open class UserRecord() : UpdatableRecordImpl<UserRecord>(User.USER), Record2<String?, String?> {

    var id: String?
        set(value): Unit = set(0, value)
        get(): String? = get(0) as String?

    var email: String?
        set(value): Unit = set(1, value)
        get(): String? = get(1) as String?

:

}
```

### Technologies

- JOOQ: 3.16.4
- Gradle
- Spring Boot: 3.0.1

Answer (score 0):

This feature will ship with jOOQ 3.18, see:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10212

You can configure:

```xml
<kotlinNotNullPojoAttributes>true</kotlinNotNullPojoAttributes>
<kotlinNotNullRecordAttributes>true</kotlinNotNullRecordAttributes>
<kotlinNotNullInterfaceAttributes>true</kotlinNotNullInterfaceAttributes>
```

Of course, beware that as documented in the above issue, and throughout jOOQ's github issues, Stack Overflow, etc., the *guarantee* of non-nullability in this case will be a "lie." When jOOQ creates a new `UserRecord` for you, then those valuse will still be `null`:

```kotlin
// Contains nulls!
val user: UserRecord = ctx.newRecord(USER)
```